# TypeError: php.cgi is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this code from this page

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php

but I get a type error on this line:

```
app.use("/", php.cgi("/path/to/wordpress"));
```

I ran `npm install php-cgi`

Maybe I should use:

```
app.use("/", php-cgi("/path/to/wordpress"));
```

but when I do I get other errors,
not read entire php-cgi only read php

TypeError: php is not a function

please help me

Comment: i just replaced **var php = require("php");** with **var php = require("node-php");** then above error gone.

Comment: great ,works very thank you ,

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure so you have installed the `php-cgi` interpreter on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

Comment: Update typing error from sudo apt-get install php5-cgi to sudo apt -get install php5-cgi